# How to add QT translations to CMake

Tags: qt, cmake

Cannot figure out how to add QT translations to CMake. I tried this:

```
file(GLOB TRANSLATION_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Translations/*.ts)
qt5_add_translation(QM_FILES ${TRANSLATION_FILES})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CPP_FILES} ${RESOURCES} ${QM_FILES})
```

When I compile VS2015 project generated with my CMake I have the following build output:

```
*2>Generating MyProj_en.qm
2>Updating 'C:/repos/build/lg/MyProj_en.qm'...
2>    Generated 14 translation(s) (14 finished and 0 unfinished)
2>Generating MyProj_ru.qm
2>Updating 'C:/repos/build/lg/MyProj_ru.qm'...*
```

so at least *.qm files are generated, but QTranslator does not load the translations:

```
static const QString translationsDirectory = ":/Translations/";
QTranslator translator;
bool loaded = translator.load(translation_file, translationsDirectory);
//here loaded == false
```

what did I miss in CMake?

**EDIT1:**

in my .pro file (with QMake) I have this:

```
TRANSLATIONS = $$files(Translations/*.ts)

qtPrepareTool(LRELEASE, lrelease)
for(tsfile, TRANSLATIONS) {
    qmfile = $$tsfile
    qmfile ~= s,.ts$,.qm,
    if (!exists($$qmfile)) {
        command = $$LRELEASE -removeidentical $$tsfile -qm $$qmfile
        system($$command)|error("Translation: Failed to run: $$command")
    }
}

#Icon files are added in the same way as in quickcontrols2\gallery\ sample
RESOURCES += qml.qrc \
    scene.qrc \
    $$files(Translations/*.qm) \
    icons.qrc
```

and C++ code above loads the translations successfully.

**EDIT2:**

tried adding QM_FILES to the resources:

```
file(GLOB TRANSLATION_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Translations/*.ts)
qt5_add_translation(QM_FILES ${TRANSLATION_FILES})

qt5_add_resources(RESOURCES qml.qrc scene.qrc icons.qrc ${QM_FILES})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CPP_FILES} ${RESOURCES})
```

but with no success, the error is:

```
CUSTOMBUILD : RCC Parse error : 'C:/repos/build/lg/MyProj_en.qm' Line: 1 Column: 2 [Encountered incorrectly encoded content.]
```

probably .qrc file is expected, but not .qm.

Comment: It might be a typical issue with visual studio - check if the working directory is really the directory you expect it to be.

Comment: The `qm` files are located at `C:/repos/build/lg/` but you specify `:/Translations/` (resources?)

Comment: Yes, looks like *.qm files are created, but are not added to the resources, see EDIT1.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit late, but:
What qmake does can be found in the code and is quite legible indeed: https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.15.2/mkspecs/features/lrelease.prf

When you check the build dir, it becomes evident that qmake produces a file named `qmake_<resource list name>.qrc` -- in this case `qmake_qmake_qm_files.qrc` --, which is then added to the `RESOURCES` list.

For cmake, my personal solution was like this (you may want to come up with something prettier):

```
  set(qmDir "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/.qm")
  file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${qmDir})

  file(GLOB_RECURSE translationFiles *.ts)
  set_source_files_properties(${translationFiles} PROPERTIES OUTPUT_LOCATION ${qmDir})
  qt5_create_translation(qmFileList ${translationFiles})

  set(qmResourcesFile "${qmDir}/${resourceFileName}.qrc")
  file(WRITE ${qmResourcesFile} "<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version=\"1.0\">\n  <qresource prefix=\"i18n\">\n")

  foreach(qm_file ${qmFileList})
    file(RELATIVE_PATH qm_filename ${qmDir} ${qm_file})
    file(APPEND ${qmResourcesFile} "    <file alias=\"${qm_filename}\">${qm_file}</file>\n")
  endforeach(qm_file)

  file(APPEND ${qmResourcesFile} "  </qresource>\n</RCC>\n")
```

And then use `qt5_add_resources` to add the `qmResourcesFile` to your sources.